# Extract data from table or list

Tags: powershell

I'm pulling data from a SQL Server query and it comes back as either a Powershell list or table.  I need two values from the results and I cannot find a way to get at them.
[image: query results in list or table format]

I need to get config_value and run_value.  I've tried

- accessing as if it were a property: $results.config_value
- accessing as a hash: $results["config_value"]
- converting it to a string and trying to parse it.

I know there's an easier way, but I haven't found it. A search on the interwebs showed all sorts of results, none of which really matched what I'm trying to do (like get data from an HTML table) or were relevant (a different language).

As requested, here's $results.GetType()  It's not at all what I expected:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

The reason I say it's not what I expected is because the code that gives the results explicitly specifies to use either a table or list:

```
    if($aslist -eq 1){
        $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows|fl
    } else {
        $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows|Format-Table -AutoSize
    } # if..else
```

I verified $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows is indeed a  System.Data.DataRowCollection.

Comment: Can you post the output of `$results.gettype()`?

Comment: what do `$Results.GetType()` and `$Results[0].GetType()` show?

Comment: Wild guess: are you further processing the output of `Format-List`/`Format-Table`? Never do that, you'll get properties of the `Format-*` cmdlets, not from your data. See `Get-ChildItem | Format-Table BaseName,Extension|Get-Member`